# What's the absolute minimum information needed to have a valid coordinate?

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates

Don't assume anything. You read a specific coordinate value.

What's the minimum information you need for unambiguous interpretation of such coordinate?

Does a coordinate has sense without specifying its Geographic Coordinate System? Should I know its notation? Anything else?

Comment: This is a rather abstract question for the "Focused Question/Best Answer" model used here.  The [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) states "Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced." This reads more like a thought experiment, without any practical, real-world application.

Comment: Au contraire, I am a software developer working on a model ontology for GIS.

Comment: Then edit the question to sound like it,  comparing the well-known text and Esri spatial reference models. Given those differences, I'd expect this to be closed as *opinion-based* or *too broad*, but at least there'd be a demonstration of prior research.

Comment: Why should I compare anything? I don't understand. This is a simple question nobody can answer? How comes you want more research if you cannot simply answer that? Now if you expect people came here to post preliminary findings for a peer-review PLoS journal article you are so confused.... look at stackoverflow and tell me % of "researched" questions.... get real, if you cannot answer, then just don't post.

Comment: If you're not assuming anything, by focusing on the geographic CRS, you've already closed off the possibility of the coordinate value being in a projected, local/engineering, vertical, Geocentric XYZ, etc coordinate reference system.

Comment: So the minimum information a coordinate needs is its CRS? All CRS defines its valid coordinates notations? How do you guess the notation if not specified?